# How can I access deletion stubs (unids)?

Tags: lotus-domino

I have an Java agent synchronizing Notes documents with rows in a MS SQL table. New documents are inserted and changed dokuments are updated, but I have not found a good way to handle deleted documents. I use JDBC.
The way I do it now is to make a list of unids on both sides and delete rows in the SQL table that does not exist in Notes.
If I could have access to a list of deletion stubs, it would be much easier and better performance. The agent runs daily.
The table contains 500.000 rows and there are 50-100 deletions in each run.

Comment: Reminder that deletion stubs will be cleared eventually.

Answer (score 1):

The only 100% foolproof way to be sure you will capture *all* deletions is to use the Notes C API Extension Manager feature to buiuld a server add-on to handle EM_BEFORE events for NSFNoteDelete calls. You could use the add-on code in the OpenNTF [TriggerHappy](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Trigger%20Happy) project to simplify this, and to allow you to write most of your actual logic Java instead of C. Your code would simply have to capture the information you need from the document that is about to be deleted (i.e., the UNID if that's all you need) and record it in another database that you can query via JDBC. You could also clean up that database via JDBC after you've done your synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Using JDBC you can't.

What you may try to do is writting an agent that will build in a separated DB the list of all the NoteID of deleted document and get this list via JDBC.
I think you can get only NoteID (not UNID), thus I suggest you to also store them in MS SQL.

Look at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/8210fa46540ecbbf852572b40044bb3e?OpenDocument for a start to build your Domino side agent.